# Exclude Redirect rule on an Alias domain - for specific file (Robots.txt)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, robots.txt, mod-alias

I have my main site: `example.com` that contains all files on its root folder.

I have a new domain `example.net`, that I want users to use as an alias domain, so users will actually see the exact content of `example.com` and its files, yet see in their address bar the site `example.net`.

But, I don't want Google to index `example.net` site at all, as this would be duplicate content.

Therefore, I want to exclude it using `robots.txt`, but if I use an alias domain, it will try to read `robots.txt` of `example.com`.

What can be the solution? any way to exclude the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-net.txt [NC,L]
```

Add your robot rules in the file `robots-net.txt` to be read with `robots.txt` but only when accessed from `example.net`.